# Is it any way to run stat function crosstab on GroupData in Spark Data Frame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I try to find solution for the following:

- I have  a `DataFrame` with 3 columns A, B, C.
- I need to `groupBy(A)` and than to run `crosstab(B and C)` per each group that is crated by `groupBy(A)` in `PySpark`

Example in Pandas (the same I'd like to create in Spak Data Frame):

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
for name, group in grouped:
    df_crossed = pd.crosstab(group['B'],group['C'])
    df_crossed = (df_crossed>0).astype(int)
    df_result[name] = df_crossed.mean(axis=1).max(axis=0)
```

Updated:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
        A      B        C
0       AB    100       5
1       AB    200       5
2       AC    150       4
3       AC    500       5
```

```
A       B          C                       
AB      100        5     
        200        5
AC      150        4     
        500        5
```

than should be crosstab for AB and AC
something like:

```
AB

C    5 
B
100  1
200  1
```

```
AC

C    5  4
B
150  0  1
500  1  0
```

Any ideas how to do it? I can' find way to implement "for" from this code
thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to merge `A` and `B` into an artificial `struct` and use it for `crosstab`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct

df.withColumn("AB", struct("A", "B")).crosstab("AB", "C")
```